# How to connect separate memcache server on Ubuntu and Use from other server?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, caching, memcached

I have LAMP based PHP & MySql web application hosted on digitalocean separate servers in Singapore region. One PHP server + one remote MySql DB server, both are working fine. Because the app has to read more than the write, I wanted to add one memcache server.

What I've tried so far: - Use these steps from this  [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-14-04)
on a 2gb droplet.

Now I have a one memcache server with public `ip:129.x.x.x` and private `ip:10.x.x.x`,

1-p 11211

2.-m 2048

3.-c 1024

4.-l 127.0.0.1

memcached server successfully installed and cached the test data on localhost. But I want to use this on other remote web server,

So I have changed in `memcached.conf` file  `-l 127.0.0.1` to THIS memcached server private IP  `-l 10.x.x.x`.

Now when I check on memcached server and type `ps aux | grep memcached` it shows:

```
tcp        0      0 10.x.x.x:11211      *:*     LISTEN     3742/memcached
```

When I check stats `echo "stats settings" | nc 10.x.x.x 11211` it shows that all things about memcached server and it is running.

For testing purposes I made a file `test.php` and save on PHP server and try to connect.

```
<?php
  $mc = new Memcached();
  $mc->addServer("**10.x.x.x**", 11211);
  $result = $mc->get("test_key");
  if($result) {
    echo $result;
  } else {
    echo "No data on Cache. Please refresh.";
    $mc->set("test_key", "test data from Cache!") or die ("Failed to save data at Memcached server");
  }
?>
```

But it is always showing an `HTTP ERROR 500` error page, a"page isn’t working error on PHP server, `192.x.x.x is currently unable to handle this request` but my other PHP and MySql app running on same server.

The same code is running and caching data successfully on memcached server but not working in remote PHP server.

When I try `telnet 10.x.x.x 11211` it is connecting successfully, `sudo iptables -L` outputs that INPUT policy ACCEPT anywhere.

I've tried a lot of googling but it is not helping me with anything.

Answer (score 0):

After checking web server error logs , that shows 
`Class 'Memcached' not found` . i have to install memcached php module in web server in order to connect to remotely memcached instance . by typing

`apt-get install php5-memcached`

and change in php.ini by adding

`extension = memcached.so` ,

than php web server start connected to remotely memcached server . if you want to use memcached for session's than open php.ini file and add

`session.save_handler = memcache
session.save_path = 'tcp://10.x.x.x:11211'`

and finally, restart server .